# How to use 'xdata' in imshow() from MatLab in Python3 imshow()

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I'm trying to convert some MatLab code to Python3 but am having trouble with one line, the line in MatLab is

```
imshow(sqrt(I),[0,100],'InitialMagnification','fit','xdata',[-1,1]*a,'ydata',[-1,1]*a);
```

Where `a` is some constant.

The problems I'm having are with `'XData'` and `'YData'`. I'm currently using the Python code

```
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(np.sqrt(np.real(I)), vmin = 0, vmax = 100)
```

How do I convert the `'XData'` and `'YData'` elements into Python?

EDIT Full Code for Python and MatLab

Python code:

(I'm sooo sorry, but I haven't commented this code yet, I can do so if needed)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

l = 633*10**(-6)
L = 10

N = 2**11
Nx = 2**11
Ny = 2**11

xmax = 5*10**(-4)
ymax = 5*10**(-4)
curlyv = np.zeros((Nx,Ny),dtype=np.double)
x = np.tile(np.linspace(-xmax,xmax,Nx),(Ny,1))
y = np.tile(np.linspace(-ymax,ymax,Ny).reshape(Ny,1),(1,Nx))
h = np.sqrt(4*np.pi/(l*L))

np_x = np.array(x)
np_y = np.array(y)

aperture = np.sqrt(np_x**2 + np_y**2) >= 100*10**-6

curlyv[aperture] = 1    

vprime = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(curlyv))
I = vprime*np.conj(vprime)
Imax = np.real(np.amax(I))
fig2 = plt.figure()
Imax_b = Imax/5000
pltp = plt.imshow(np.sqrt(np.real(I)), vmin = 0, vmax = 100, cmap='Greys_r', extent=(-Nx/h*1000, Nx/h*1000, -Ny/h*1000, Ny/h*1000))

plt.show()
```

Python image:

[image: Python Image]

MatLab Code

```
% This script calculates, via a 2D Fourier Transform, the Fraunhofer diffraction
% pattern due to a circular aperture. Source plane is the xy-plane. The field plane
% is at a distance L from the source plane.

lambda = 633e-6; L = 10;                     % meters

% Set up the source plane domain and initialize the source plane amplitude (curlyv) at each point
N=2^11; Nx = N; Ny = N;                         % resolution (pixels)
xmax=5e-4;                                  % meters
ymax=5e-4;                                  % meters
curlyv = zeros(Nx,Ny);                      % curlyv has one complex value at each location (x,y)
x=repmat(linspace(-xmax,xmax,Nx),Ny,1);     % x domain (source plane)
y=repmat(linspace(-ymax,ymax,Ny)',1,Nx);    % y domain (source plane)
h = sqrt(4*pi/(lambda*L));                  % axes scaling (from the theory)

% construct a logical vector corresponding to the (x,y)-locations where the incident field is
% non-zero. Only need to set these elements of curlyv so some non-zero values
% corresponding to the incident field's complex amplitude.

aperture = sqrt(x.^2+y.^2) >= 100e-6;       % logical vector giving aperture shape
% The incident field ampli0tude u(x,y) is just 1 everywhere in the aperture. The additional
% exponential corresponding to the phase in curlyv is formally required from the theory but can be omitted to a good
% approximation in most cases.
curlyv(aperture)=1;                         %exp(1i*h^2*(x(aperture).^2+y(aperture).^2));

figure(1);
iptsetpref('ImShowAxesVisible','On');
imshow(curlyv,[-0.5 1],'InitialMagnification','fit',...
    'xdata',[-xmax, xmax]*1000,'ydata',[-ymax,ymax]*1000); % display the diffraction pattern
vprime = fftshift(fft2(curlyv,Nx,Nx));      % perform the 2D FT to get the field plane field amplitude
I = conj(vprime).*vprime;                   % calculate intensity
xlabel('mm'); ylabel('mm');

figure(2);
Imax=max(max(I));
iptsetpref('ImShowAxesVisible','On');
imshow(sqrt(I),[0,sqrt(Imax)/50],'InitialMagnification','fit','xdata',[-1,1]*Nx/h*1000,'ydata',[-1,1]*Ny/h*1000); % display the diffraction pattern

colormap(bone); shg;  shading interp;
axis([-2,2,-2,2]*1000);       % 0 =  black, Imax/10 = white (so many pixels will be saturated)
xlabel('mm'); ylabel('mm');
```

MatLab Image (what the images should look like)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`XData` for `imshow` in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html#input_argument_namevalue_xdata) sets the

> Limits along X axis of a nondefault spatial coordinate system, specified as a two-element vector

(similar for `YData` and the y axis). For [`matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`, the `extent` parameter](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) seems to have the same effect:

> **extent** : scalars (left, right, bottom, top), optional, default: `None`
>
> The location, in data-coordinates, of the lower-left and upper-right corners. If `None`, the image is positioned such that the pixel centers fall on zero-based (row, column) indices.

Hence the equivalent call would be

```
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(np.sqrt(np.real(I)), vmin = 0, vmax = 100, extent=(-a, a, -a, a))
```

Comment: Thanks for the information but xdata and ydata have to do something more than just changing the 'axes' of the image (I think) as the image that I get from python with or without extent is the same as the image I get from MatLab when NOT using xdata, ydata, but with extend in Python, I don't get the same image as MatLab. I verified all the variables I'm using in Python are the same as those in MatLab. I don't want to bother too much but do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @John I fixed my typo (minus in wrong place). If that does not fix it for you, can you edit your post to show actual data, and results? (it seems to produce the same result with `extent` and `XData`/`YData` here, except `imshow` makes `axes` invisible and pyplot doesn't)

Comment: I saw the issue with the signs and fixed that. I edited the main post with code and output.

Comment: @John OK, your MATLAB code has a call to `axis([-2,2,-2,2]*1000);`, which sets the visible x and y ranges. The equivalent in `pyplot` is `plt.xlim(-2000, 2000)`, `plt.ylim(-2000, 2000)`. Then the color ranges are different. try setting `vmax=81252.72`.

Comment: You're literally my hero! Thanks!!